# How do I print a function in a string?

Tags: python, string, function

So I am trying to do a simple calculation using Python 2.7 the code is as follows:

```
print 'In SchmooLand everyone is 9.33356564 times heavier than on earth.\n'

weight = float(raw_input('How much do you weigh on Earth in pounds?\n'))

print 'In SchmooLand you would weigh' 
print weight * 9.3356564 
print 'in pounds'
```

The output looks like this though

```
How much do you weigh on Earth in pounds?
235423423
In SchmooLand you would weigh
2197832185.64
in pounds
```

How do I print the result of the weight calculation on the same line as the string so it would all print together like this

```
In SchmooLand you would weigh 2197832185.64 in pounds
```

I'm a total n00b - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a comma to the end of each print line to avoid the implicit newline:

```
print 'In SchmooLand you would weigh',
print weight * 9.3356564,
print 'in pounds',
```

From the `print` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

> A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma.

Comment: You rock! Thank you very much! It won't let me mark as an answer for another 12 min but I will be sure to mark it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
print 'In SchmooLand you would weigh {} in pounds'.format(weight * 9.3356564)
```

The `{}` will be replaced by parameter of the `format()` method.

Comment: So does {} tell the script to automatically look for a format() method?

Comment: `format()` looks for `{}`. Look up Python string formatting to find out all it's uses, it can be quite versatile.

Answer (score 1):

```
weight = float(raw_input('How much do you weigh on Earth in pounds?\n')) * 9.3356564

print 'In SchmooLand you would weigh', weight, 'in pounds'
```